# Python telebot not working properly while executing scripts from my server

Tags: python, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api, telebot

I've created a telegram bot using `telebot` or `pyTelegramBotAPI` and created a command in it that let's users execute a python script from my server the script actually scrapes information from lots of websites and then display it back to user using`requests` library. This is my approach to do it

```
import telebot
import requests

from functions.scrape import scrape

API_KEY = 'MY_KEY'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_KEY)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])

def help(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, """
        ℹ️ **Command Menu** ℹ️
       /help - Displays the command menu
       /run - scrape information
""")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['run'])

def run(pm):
    values = scrape()
    bot.send_message(pm.chat.id, f"scraped values: {values}")

bot.polling()
```

The script works fine and does execute the `scrape` function however some requests from
my script automatically fails (out of 300 only 170 requests succeed)

Note - I know the problem lies with telebot itself and not my script cause when i run the same script on my server directly it works flawless without any failed requests i wanted to know what possible reasons might be causing it and how can i fix it or if there any other alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use to run some telegram bots but I only used the [python-telegram-bot](https://python-telegram-bot.org/) API (that I recommend, by the way) and I don't know about the `telebot` API.

Considering that it works out of the `telebot` context, most likely your decorator `@bot.message_handler` might add some kind of a timeout on the function to be used as a message handler (which makes sense)...

Something you could try is to launch the compute (scrapping) in another thread, and directly return the message_handler function. Then later on the thread would send your result with `bot.send_message`, avoiding any timeout

Comment: thanks for your help though could you share some code snippet on how to do that and i'll be sure to look at python-telegram-bot . Thanks a ton for your help again

Comment: One example of how to achieve this :
`from threading import Thread` on top
And then :
`@bot.message_handler(commands=['run'])
def run(pm):
    t = Thread(target=compute, args=[pm.chat.id])
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()

def compute(chat_id):
    values = scrape()
    bot.send_message(chat_id, f"scraped values: {values}")`
(EDIT) Sorry, comment seem to remove line breaks...